# XPath not returning Node Value ASP.NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, xpath

Having a small issue here, I am working on converting a legacy Classic ASP application to ASP.NET 4.5 for a customer and have the need to pull data from an XML file but I cannot get the value of a single node, my code just returns nothing.

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Devices-Detail-Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.embeddeddatasystems.com/schema/owserver">
<PollCount>150722</PollCount>
<DevicesConnected>4</DevicesConnected>
<LoopTime>3.974</LoopTime>
<DataErrors>2</DataErrors>
<DeviceName>OW_SERVER-Enet</DeviceName>
<HostName>EDSOWSERVER</HostName
<MACAddress>00:50:C2:91:B3:9C</MACAddress>
<owd_DS18B20 Description="Programmable resolution thermometer">
<Name>DS18B20</Name>
<Family>28</Family>
<ROMId>2D0000023C519A28</ROMId>
<Health>7</Health>
<RawData>0E014B467FFF021000000</RawData>
<PrimaryValue>16.8750 Deg C</PrimaryValue>
<Temperature Units="Centigrade">16.8750</Temperature>
<UserByte1 Writable="True">75</UserByte1>
<UserByte2 Writable="True">70</UserByte2>
<Resolution>12</Resolution>
<PowerSource>0</PowerSource>
</owd_DS18B20>
<owd_DS18B20 Description="Programmable resolution thermometer">
<Name>DS18B20</Name>
<Family>28</Family>
<ROMId>DA000002E0E5A928</ROMId>
<Health>7</Health>
<RawData>32014B467FFF0E101E000000</RawData>
<PrimaryValue>19.1250 Deg C</PrimaryValue>
<Temperature Units="Centigrade">19.1250</Temperature>
<UserByte1 Writable="True">75</UserByte1>
<UserByte2 Writable="True">70</UserByte2>
<Resolution>12</Resolution>
<PowerSource>0</PowerSource>
</owd_DS18B20>
<owd_DS18B20 Description="Programmable resolution thermometer">
<Name>DS18B20</Name>
<Family>28</Family>
<ROMId>C3000002E0EE1B28</ROMId>
<Health>7</Health>
<RawData>1D014B467FFF0310C5000000</RawData>
<PrimaryValue>17.8125 Deg C</PrimaryValue>
<Temperature Units="Centigrade">17.8125</Temperature>
<UserByte1 Writable="True">75</UserByte1>
<UserByte2 Writable="True">70</UserByte2>
<Resolution>12</Resolution>
<PowerSource>0</PowerSource>
</owd_DS18B20>
<owd_DS18B20 Description="Programmable resolution thermometer">
<Name>DS18B20</Name>
<Family>28</Family>
<ROMId>070000023DBB7F28</ROMId>
<Health>7</Health>
<RawData>52014B467FFF0E10FFFF0000000000000000</RawData>
<PrimaryValue>21.1250 Deg C</PrimaryValue>
<Temperature Units="Centigrade">21.1250</Temperature>
<UserByte1 Writable="True">75</UserByte1>
<UserByte2 Writable="True">70</UserByte2>
<Resolution>12</Resolution>
<PowerSource>255</PowerSource>
</owd_DS18B20>
</Devices-Detail-Response>
```

I need to be able to get the Temperature value based on the ROMId as there can be upto 22 sensors connected at any one time.

I have tried the following but it always yeilds nothing:

```
Imports System.Xml
Dim m_xmld As XmlDocument
Dim m_nodelist As XmlNodeList
Dim m_node As XmlNode
Dim Temperature As String = String.Empty

m_xmld = New XmlDocument()
m_xmld.Load("http://" & server_ip & "/details.xml")
Dim m_xmlns As New XmlNamespaceManager(m_xmld.NameTable)
m_xmlns.AddNamespace("opsm_ns", "http://tempuri.org/zitem.xsd")

For Each node As XmlNode In
m_xmld.SelectNodes("//opsm_ns:owd_DS18B20[ROMId='" & deviceId & "']",m_xmlns)
Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes("Temperature").Value)
Next
```

The document loads but I simply cannot get the data out as nothing is returned, what am I missing here??

Thanks in advance

Ozzie

**UPDATE 2: Have grabbed the full XML output in Visual Studio and updated above**

**UPDATE 3: Have used the example from @CrnaStena below with the above XML and still does not return any value**

Comment: You seem to be selecting ROMid node which does not have temperature attribute. You'll have to get nodes parent then look for child nodes with name temperature.

Comment: I have tried selectin g the root node "/Devices-Detail-Response" but this does not return anything.  This was how I did it in the old classic asp way: `Dim strXPath : strXPath = "/Devices-Detail-Response/owd_DS18B20[ROMId='" & strName & "']"
Dim xmlSensor       
For Each xmlSensor In objXML.documentElement.selectNodes(strXPath)
     Dim romID : romID = xmlSensor.selectSingleNode("ROMId").text   
     Dim temperature : temperature = xmlSensor.selectSingleNode("Temperature").text 
     Response.Write Server.HTMLEncode(temperature) & "<br /><br />"   
Next`

Comment: If i step through the code in visual studio i can see the document is loading sucessfully but as we move through it the data/nodes are not available

Comment: I finally got to the computer, see my answer and let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Why are you using a namespace prefix when your XML doesn't?  All the nodes in your sample XML are in the default namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is my LinqPad example in C#, sorry I have not used VB in 20 years. I've expanded your XML to add additional node which has different ROMid and temperature.

```
void Main()
{
        // XML to load
    var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<Devices-Detail-Response>
    <PollCount>36593</PollCount>
    <DevicesConnected>2</DevicesConnected>
    <LoopTime>1.031</LoopTime>
    <DataErrors>0</DataErrors>
    <DeviceName>OW_SERVER-Enet</DeviceName>
    <HostName>EDSOWSERVER</HostName>
    <MACAddress>00:50:C2:91:B3:9C</MACAddress>
    <owd_DS18B20 Description=""Programmable resolution thermometer"">
        <Name>DS18B20</Name>
        <Family>28</Family>
        <ROMId>2D0000023C519A28</ROMId>
        <Health>7</Health>
        <RawData>61014B467FFF0F1002FF</RawData>
        <PrimaryValue>22.0625 Deg C</PrimaryValue>
        <Temperature Units=""Centigrade"">22.0625</Temperature>
        <UserByte1 Writable=""True"">75</UserByte1>
        <UserByte2 Writable=""True"">70</UserByte2>
        <Resolution>12</Resolution>
        <PowerSource>255</PowerSource>
    </owd_DS18B20>
    <owd_DS18B20 Description=""Programmable resolution thermometer"">
        <Name>DS18B20</Name>
        <Family>28</Family>
        <ROMId>2D0000023C519A29</ROMId>
        <Health>7</Health>
        <RawData>61014B467FFF0F1002FF</RawData>
        <PrimaryValue>22.0625 Deg C</PrimaryValue>
        <Temperature Units=""Centigrade"">24.0625</Temperature>
        <UserByte1 Writable=""True"">75</UserByte1>
        <UserByte2 Writable=""True"">70</UserByte2>
        <Resolution>12</Resolution>
        <PowerSource>255</PowerSource>
    </owd_DS18B20>  
</Devices-Detail-Response>";

    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

    var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//owd_DS18B20/ROMId[text()='2D0000023C519A28']/../Temperature");
    foreach(XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        node.InnerText.Dump();
    }


}
```

And result shows `22.0625`

**Update 1**

And I brushed up on VB and here is LinqPad VB code with same result:

```
Sub Main
    Dim xml As String
    Dim m_xmld As XmlDocument

    xml = <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Devices-Detail-Response>
    <PollCount>36593</PollCount>
    <DevicesConnected>2</DevicesConnected>
    <LoopTime>1.031</LoopTime>
    <DataErrors>0</DataErrors>
    <DeviceName>OW_SERVER-Enet</DeviceName>
    <HostName>EDSOWSERVER</HostName>
    <MACAddress>00:50:C2:91:B3:9C</MACAddress>
    <owd_DS18B20 Description="Programmable resolution thermometer">
        <Name>DS18B20</Name>
        <Family>28</Family>
        <ROMId>2D0000023C519A28</ROMId>
        <Health>7</Health>
        <RawData>61014B467FFF0F1002FF</RawData>
        <PrimaryValue>22.0625 Deg C</PrimaryValue>
        <Temperature Units="Centigrade">22.0625</Temperature>
        <UserByte1 Writable="True">75</UserByte1>
        <UserByte2 Writable="True">70</UserByte2>
        <Resolution>12</Resolution>
        <PowerSource>255</PowerSource>
    </owd_DS18B20>
    <owd_DS18B20 Description="Programmable resolution thermometer">
        <Name>DS18B20</Name>
        <Family>28</Family>
        <ROMId>2D0000023C519A29</ROMId>
        <Health>7</Health>
        <RawData>61014B467FFF0F1002FF</RawData>
        <PrimaryValue>22.0625 Deg C</PrimaryValue>
        <Temperature Units="Centigrade">24.0625</Temperature>
        <UserByte1 Writable="True">75</UserByte1>
        <UserByte2 Writable="True">70</UserByte2>
        <Resolution>12</Resolution>
        <PowerSource>255</PowerSource>
    </owd_DS18B20>  
</Devices-Detail-Response>]]>.Value

    m_xmld = New XmlDocument()
    m_xmld.LoadXml(xml)
    'Dim m_xmlns As New XmlNamespaceManager(m_xmld.NameTable)
    'm_xmlns.AddNamespace("opsm_ns", "http://tempuri.org/zitem.xsd")
    Dim deviceId As String = "2D0000023C519A28"

    For Each node As XmlNode In m_xmld.SelectNodes("//owd_DS18B20/ROMId[text()='" & deviceId & "']/../Temperature")
        node.InnerText.Dump()
    Next

End Sub
```

**Update 2** - This works. Your XML is missing closing tag for `</HostName>`. You will also have to specify namespace for every tag along the XPath.

```
 //opsm_ns:owd_DS18B20/opsm_ns:ROMId[text()='" & deviceId & "']/../opsm_ns:Temperature
```

Here is the whole mini-program.

```
Sub Main
    Dim xml As String
    Dim m_xmld As XmlDocument

    xml = <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Devices-Detail-Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.embeddeddatasystems.com/schema/owserver">
<PollCount>150722</PollCount>
<DevicesConnected>4</DevicesConnected>
<LoopTime>3.974</LoopTime>
<DataErrors>2</DataErrors>
<DeviceName>OW_SERVER-Enet</DeviceName>
<HostName>EDSOWSERVER</HostName>
<MACAddress>00:50:C2:91:B3:9C</MACAddress>
<owd_DS18B20 Description="Programmable resolution thermometer">
<Name>DS18B20</Name>
<Family>28</Family>
<ROMId>2D0000023C519A28</ROMId>
<Health>7</Health>
<RawData>0E014B467FFF021000000</RawData>
<PrimaryValue>16.8750 Deg C</PrimaryValue>
<Temperature Units="Centigrade">16.8750</Temperature>
<UserByte1 Writable="True">75</UserByte1>
<UserByte2 Writable="True">70</UserByte2>
<Resolution>12</Resolution>
<PowerSource>0</PowerSource>
</owd_DS18B20>
<owd_DS18B20 Description="Programmable resolution thermometer">
<Name>DS18B20</Name>
<Family>28</Family>
<ROMId>DA000002E0E5A928</ROMId>
<Health>7</Health>
<RawData>32014B467FFF0E101E000000</RawData>
<PrimaryValue>19.1250 Deg C</PrimaryValue>
<Temperature Units="Centigrade">19.1250</Temperature>
<UserByte1 Writable="True">75</UserByte1>
<UserByte2 Writable="True">70</UserByte2>
<Resolution>12</Resolution>
<PowerSource>0</PowerSource>
</owd_DS18B20>
<owd_DS18B20 Description="Programmable resolution thermometer">
<Name>DS18B20</Name>
<Family>28</Family>
<ROMId>C3000002E0EE1B28</ROMId>
<Health>7</Health>
<RawData>1D014B467FFF0310C5000000</RawData>
<PrimaryValue>17.8125 Deg C</PrimaryValue>
<Temperature Units="Centigrade">17.8125</Temperature>
<UserByte1 Writable="True">75</UserByte1>
<UserByte2 Writable="True">70</UserByte2>
<Resolution>12</Resolution>
<PowerSource>0</PowerSource>
</owd_DS18B20>
<owd_DS18B20 Description="Programmable resolution thermometer">
<Name>DS18B20</Name>
<Family>28</Family>
<ROMId>070000023DBB7F28</ROMId>
<Health>7</Health>
<RawData>52014B467FFF0E10FFFF0000000000000000</RawData>
<PrimaryValue>21.1250 Deg C</PrimaryValue>
<Temperature Units="Centigrade">21.1250</Temperature>
<UserByte1 Writable="True">75</UserByte1>
<UserByte2 Writable="True">70</UserByte2>
<Resolution>12</Resolution>
<PowerSource>255</PowerSource>
</owd_DS18B20>
</Devices-Detail-Response>]]>.Value

    m_xmld = New XmlDocument()
    m_xmld.LoadXml(xml)
    Dim m_xmlns As New XmlNamespaceManager(m_xmld.NameTable)
    m_xmlns.AddNamespace("opsm_ns", "http://www.embeddeddatasystems.com/schema/owserver")
    Dim deviceId As String = "2D0000023C519A28"

    For Each node As XmlNode In m_xmld.SelectNodes("//opsm_ns:owd_DS18B20/opsm_ns:ROMId[text()='" & deviceId & "']/../opsm_ns:Temperature", m_xmlns)
        node.InnerText.Dump()
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestions an unfortunately as dan field's suggestion I yeild no results.  I will post up the full XML output from the innerXML in a moment just incase we are missing something.

Comment: OK so used your email from Update 1  with the full XML that I have updated above and yep does not return a value.  I changed the Select Nodes line to include the full path from the root but still nothing :-(

Comment: Sorry i meant example and NOT email in the above comment.

Comment: Ok, I added example that works with namespaces. See **Update 2**.

Comment: Worked but had to remove .Dump() as it is not supported, new to XML namespaces so helped alot, thanks again :-)

Comment: Yeah `Dump()` is LinqPad extension.

Answer (score 2):

Your XML is in the default namespace, but you're attempting to read nodes that are in a specified namespace.  Change this:

```
m_xmld = New XmlDocument()
m_xmld.Load("http://" & server_ip & "/details.xml")
Dim m_xmlns As New XmlNamespaceManager(m_xmld.NameTable)
m_xmlns.AddNamespace("opsm_ns", "http://tempuri.org/zitem.xsd")

For Each node As XmlNode In
m_xmld.SelectNodes("//opsm_ns:owd_DS18B20[ROMId='" & deviceId & "']",m_xmlns)
Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes("Temperature").Value)
Next
```

to this:

```
m_xmld = New XmlDocument()
m_xmld.Load("http://" & server_ip & "/details.xml")
/* Dim m_xmlns As New XmlNamespaceManager(m_xmld.NameTable)
m_xmlns.AddNamespace("opsm_ns", "http://tempuri.org/zitem.xsd") */

For Each node As XmlNode In
m_xmld.SelectNodes("//owd_DS18B20[ROMId='" & deviceId & "']") /*,m_xmlns)*/
Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes("Temperature").Value)
Next
```

Or, using your new update, which is in a namespace (but different from what you were actually using, you could do this):

```
m_xmld = New XmlDocument()
m_xmld.Load("http://" & server_ip & "/details.xml")
Dim m_xmlns As New XmlNamespaceManager(m_xmld.NameTable)
m_xmlns.AddNamespace("opsm_ns", "http://www.embeddeddatasystems.com/schema/owserver")

For Each node As XmlNode In
m_xmld.SelectNodes("//opsm_ns:owd_DS18B20[ROMId='" & deviceId & "']",m_xmlns)
Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes("Temperature").Value)
Next
```

If it turns out that your XML does actually contain namespaces in some instances but not others, but you know you always want that node by name, you could use the `local-name()` function like so:

```
m_xmld.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='owd_DS18B20'][ROMId='" & deviceId & "']")
```

Comment: Ha, in my sample I also disabled namespace, but I did not know about local-name. Learning something new everyday. Thanks.

Comment: I missed that in yours - wasn't quite sure what you had changed

Comment: @DanField I have tried your suggestion and as soon as we hit the for each loop it bails out as the node as xmlnode is empty??  I did try your other suggestion but this made no difference.  I really dont understand as there is no issue in connecting to the xml source.

Comment: Updated my answer.  Your actual XML instance uses a new namespace.

Comment: @DanField, the changes worked but I had to change the selectnodes path as per CrnaStena's update and change node.attributes("").values to node.innerText for the value to be returned.  Thanks for you help, never used XML namespaces before so learned something new here :-)